# lstinputlisting unable to find file if path includes dots but does not have an extension in some Linux distributions but not others

Tags: listings, paths

I am preparing a document using, rotating between Arch, Manjaro, openSUSE Tumbleweed, and Kubuntu. In Manjaro and Ubuntu, I am getting a listings package error in that the file specified is not able to be found.

The error in the log from Kubuntu:

```
! Package Listings Error: File `./ord-server-etc/etc-amavis.original/conf(.d/15-
content_filter_mode)' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: d/15-content_filter_mode)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.18 ...vis.original/conf.d/15-content_filter_mode}}

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

The error in the log in Manjaro:

```
! Package Listings Error: File `(./ord-server-etc/etc-amavis.original/conf.d/15-
content_filter_mode)' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: /ord-server-etc/etc-amavis.original/conf.
d/15-content_filter_mode)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.18 ...vis.original/conf.d/15-content_filter_mode}}

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

The error is the same (file not found), but the behavior is different. In Kubuntu everything after the **last** `.` is assumed to be the extension of the file, while in Manjaro everything after the **first** `.` is assumed to be the extension.

LuaLaTeX is assuming that everything past the last dot in the file is an extension. I have tried adding a third set of `{}` around the filepath as suggested elsewhere for a similar problem with `includegraphics`, but it does not help and causes other errors.

I am not getting the error in Arch and openSUSE. The first screenshot shows the compiled MWE document preview in TexStudio, without errors on Arch. The second screenshot shows the same MWE failing to compile in TeXstudio on Ubuntu. I am wondering why the error occurs in these two implementations and how it can be tracked down.

At first I thought the problem was only in the second use of `lstinputlisting`, below, within the separate environment. Actually, neither use of `lstinputlisting` work in Manjaro and Kubuntu.

I would like to know what the source of the discrepancy is, but more importantly:

1) I would like to make adjustments so that this error doesn't occur and I can compile the document on Kubuntu and Manjaro as well as Arch and openSUSE.
2) Can someone explain how the default extension is set. I have seen in some uses of `lstinputlisting` where LaTeX/LuaLaTeX assumes a default file extension of `.tex` when the file specified does not have an extension.

Response to Comments:

1 -  Ulrike Fischer) 
In Kubuntu: `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)` 
In Arch: `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)`
2 -  Ulrike Fischer)
I have done as you suggested for all four distributions. Two use versions of LaTeX from 2018 and the other two use a version form 2019 and there is a variation in LuaLaTeX formats but there seems to not be a correlation as to which version is causing the errors.

[image: Compiled MWE in TexStudio on Arch Linux (Working)]

[image: Same MWI Fails to Compile in TexStudio on Kubuntu]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\author{TeXstudio Team}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\date{January 2013}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\lstinputlisting[nolol,linerange={13-14},firstnumber=13,numbers=left,title={Enabling virus filtering}]{{./ord-server-etc/etc-amavis.original/conf.d/15-content_filter_mode}}

\begin{lstinputlisting}
    [nolol,linerange={13-14},firstnumber=13,numbers=left,title={Enabling virus filtering}]{{./ord-server-etc/etc-amavis.original/conf.d/15-content_filter_mode}}
    \end{lstinputlisting}
\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which luatex versions are involved?

Comment: Compare the log-files, to find differences in the package versions/latex versions.

Comment: In my original question I asked for an explanation of the discrepency. But more important is how I can resolve the error so that these documents compile on the two distributions where it is currently failing.

Comment: there was a bug in the luatex engine which prevented it to include files without extension (see e.g. https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/236). If this is the source of your problem there is not much you can do apart from changing the file names.